# UML: disjoint vs. overlapping academic scrap?

Tags: uml

It's not a real programming (coding) problem, sorry for that (but design comes first).

I don't understand the difference between `disjoint` and `overlapping`. It occurs in several books, has a relation to `OCL`, which is considered part of `UML`, but the latest OCL specification by OMG no longer mentions these terms; therefore, it appears somewhat ill-defined to me. I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify what's behind this. Is it simply multiple-inheritance of the same super-class?

Comment: Even a link to a discussion of this topic may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is covered in the current 2.2 superstructure specification, on page 76 (printed page), section 7.3.21, quotes below.  It has to do with rules of generalization and set theory.  You can search the web for sub-type and disjoint and read non-UML examples, they should apply. Although Figure 7.4 8 looks helpful and is in the examples starting on page 78.  Ok, I read the examples in the spec, they nail it down, but with pictures so I cannot easily copy those.

Text from one example: {complete, disjoint}

> Because this
>   GeneralizationSet is partitioned (i.e., is constrained to be complete and disjoint), each instance of Person must either be a
>   Female Person or a Male Person; that is, it must be one or the other and not both.

http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.2/Superstructure/PDF/

The spec lays out all the combinations.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that a superclass A has two subclasses B and C.

We say that the inheritance relationship between A, B and C is disjoint when A instances cannot be at the same time B instances and C instances (i.e. instances of a supertype only appear at most in a subclass). Otherwise, we say the inheritance set is overlapping

By default, implementation of inheritance in OO languages is disjoint.